# How to feed input to another file that it is executed in the same Java aplication with batch command?

Tags: java, batch-file

My Java aplication reads some numbers from a excel file. I need to pass these numbers to a CLIPS file as the input. After that I run with the batch command the CLIPS file and I need to collect the output and display it back in the Java aplication.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but why not use pipes?

```
java YourApp -excel 1 2 3 | otherCommand | java YourApp -otherOption
```

Comment: here is a link of something similar : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE12umWHvvk I want to be able to pass the numbers from excel to that Clips file as the input parameters